# Azure Portal Login automatically uses Windows Account

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, authentication

In **Internet Explorer**, when I go to any site that is authenticated via Azure AD, the login page automatically chooses to log me in with my Windows Account.  This functionality would typically be great, but I need to use different credentials (my clients).

How can tell IE to NOT automatically log me into Azure AD with my windows credentials?

When I use any different browser, the expected functionality exists and I am prompted to enter the login credentials I want. Also, the solution can not be "just use a different browser".  Client uses IE for everything and won't allow users to install different browsers.

I am running Windows 10.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing wrong with IE or Azure. Someone changed the settings in IE's "Security" tab. By default, the "User Authentication/Logon" setting is set to "Automatically Logon Only in Intranet Zone". If someone added the Azure portal to the Intranet zone, or the Trusted Zone and changed the settings or someone set all security zones to the lowest setting

Answer (score 2):

Opening IE InPrivate window should allow you to login with any user you need.
Use Ctrl+Shift+P or Settings Icon->Safety->InPrivate Browsing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I can not ask the client to always open IE in private.  I am looking to disassociate IE and Windows

Comment: @user959729 there's nothing wrong with IE, Azure or Windows. *All* browsers use the settings in IE's Security Tab to control automatic logging. If it's set to "Automatically logon always", the current credentials will always be used. If an authentication cookie is cached, all browsers will send it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the reply.  I have checked this setting and I've updated this, for all zones, to be "prompt for user name and password".  It previously was set to "Automatic login only in Intranet zone".  I've additionally cleared my cache and restarted the browser and am still getting the same functionality.